# Using HTML form field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm designing a website for a client who wants a 'Store Locator', but whats the user to be able to specify the distance from their postcode. To do this, I will use a simple HTML dropdown list, but how do I get this result into my Javascript equation?

This my HTML

```
<select name="radius" id="radius">
  <option value="5">5 Miles</option>
  <option value="10">10 Miles</option>
  <option value="15">15 Miles</option>
  <option value="20">20 Miles</option>
</select>
```

And this is my javascript bit which assigns the variables

```
var parameters = 'lat='+ location.lat() + '&lng=' + location.lng() + '&radius=' ?
```

What do I need to put after '&radius=' to use the result of my list as the radius variable?

Comment: Just to note, what you list there is not _JSON_, it is Javascript code. "JSON" is JavaScript Object Notation, used to represent _data_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the selected value of a select input

```
document.getElementById('radius').value
```

so your string would be

```
var parameters = 'lat='+ location.lat() + '&lng=' + location.lng() + '&radius=' document.getElementById('radius').value
```

Comment: Apologies, I mistakingly edited your answer.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I supposed something weird happen. But don't worry, it  happens :)

Comment: Rollback to the rescue!

Comment: Thank you so much Yerko, that was spot on! I've been trying everything to get it to work. Brilliant!!!

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected value from the `select` field you could use:

```
var radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;

var parameters = 'lat='+ location.lat() + '&lng=' + location.lng() + '&radius=' radius
```

Comment: Why not `document.getElementById("radius").value`?

Comment: @TerrySeidler—your point is…? The answer to that question should have been "*selectedIndex is only required for ancient versions of Netscape Navigator that are utterly dysfunctional on the modern web, or for getting the values of a multiple select*". This question isn't about a multiple select element.

Comment: I have changed the solution based on your input @RobG. This is simpler in this case.

Answer (score 0):

See [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript).

Instead of using getElementById, you are going to use [getElementByName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) to pull in the element.

Comment: There is no *getElementByName*, and please don't reference w3schools.  [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) and relevant specifications are much better. And *getElementById* is preferred here as it always returns a single element (or *null*), whereas *getElementsByName* can return either a single element or a collection.

Comment: Sorry, missed the 's' on Elements.  And with just the small snippet of code here, I agree that _getElementById_ is probably the better choice